# Laravel sending E-Mail does not work

Tags: email, laravel, smtp, laravel-5.1, swiftmailer

I am trying to sent emails with laravel but somehow it does not work I get following message:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421
>   Cannot connect to SMTP server 52.20.34.166 (52.20.34.166:587), connect
>   error 10060 "

my .env file looks like this:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=rFhHPTfEg4nxYEeqVzoQWX70a0AA5uw3

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@test.de
MAIL_PASSWORD=123456789
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

my mail.php looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', ''),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'test@test.de', 'name' => 'test'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

And inside of my Controlller I called it like this:

```
    # Send Mail
    Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->from($data['email'] , $data['title']);
        $message->to('test@test.de', 'my name')->subject('contact request');
    });
```

I cannot find the mistake in my code. Thanks for help.

Comment: Try changing port 587 to 25, 465, or 2525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other thing I notices that `mailtrap` gives you specific `username` and `password`. Did you try to use them instead of `test@test.de;123456789` ?

Comment: Yep this is somehow to answer. I forgot to create an account at mailtrap.io

Answer (score 0):

You need put a valid email on `.env`, find your personal mail configuration and try again with this.

Maybe you want to change the config `from`  on  `config/mail.php` to show your name and mail.

I say this because I see that you have the host `mailtrap.io`, but `test@test.de` is not a valid user for this host.

And maybe 587 to the `MAIL_PORT` is not the correct value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

It works for it before your changed env file and type this command and run it. It will work.